# IIS, VMWare, DR

Tags: iis, vmware, disaster-recovery

We have a number of web servers in our VMWare environment. I am a developer (not a sys admin) so I am not familiar with VMWare, but our IT team currently feels the best way to maintain a DR site is to maintain multiple VMWare servers and each time I make changes in IIS in production, I need to make the same changes on the DR VMWare server. This seems like excessive work as well as risky - considering it requires manual redundant configuration.

Is there a way where we can replicate our production VMWare servers to a DR server, and retain IIS settings, file permissions, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy/) to sync our production server across multiple locations.

Comment: This looks like something that can help us, especially the automated scripting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- [Site Recovery Manager](http://www.vmware.com/products/site-recovery-manager/overview.html)  allows you to create an entire
  alternative site on standby.
- But on a local level, placing those servers in a High Availability
  cluster is pretty standard procedure. If one server goes down, the
  machines go up in another ESX.
- Fault Tolerance is also a useful feature here, although limited to
  single-CPU VMs.